# How to decrypt data using AWS-KMS and fix the error "unencryptedDataKey has not been set"?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms

I am using **AWS KMS**, following their [official Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/js-examples.html), to encrypt data using a Master Key, which I have setup accordingly in AWS Management Console.

Encryption seems to work fine.

But when I want to decrypt the encrypted cypher-text, I get the following error:

> unencryptedDataKey has not been set

This is my code:

```
const generatorKeyId = 'arn:aws:kms:eu-central-1:51426*****:alias/my-key';
const keyIds = [];

const keyring = new KmsKeyringNode({ generatorKeyId, keyIds });

console.log(keyring);
```

This shows me:

```
KmsKeyringNode {
  clientProvider: [Function (anonymous)],
  keyIds: [],
  generatorKeyId: 'arn:aws:kms:eu-central-1:51426*****:alias/my-key',
  grantTokens: undefined,
  isDiscovery: false,
  discoveryFilter: undefined
}
```

Continue code:

```
const context = {
  stage: 'demo',
  purpose: 'simple demonstration app',
  origin: 'eu-central-1',
};

/* Create a string to encrypt */
const cleartext = 'my-cypher-teststring';

const { encrypt, decrypt } = buildClient(CommitmentPolicy.REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_REQUIRE_DECRYPT);

const { result } = await encrypt(keyring, cleartext, { encryptionContext: context });
console.log("RESULT", result)
```

Console looks like this then:

> RESULT <Buffer 02 05 78 02 4b 48 c9 96 75 f8 08 5e 33 d0 91 18 67 51
> 31 4c 7a 9d a9 ac bd df e

```
const { plaintext, messageHeader } = await decrypt(keyring, result);
console.log("Plaintext", plaintext)
console.log("MessageHeader", messageHeader)
```

Decrypt will throw the following exception:

```
Error  AM [ExceptionsHandler] unencryptedDataKey has not been set - {
    stack: [
      'Error: unencryptedDataKey has not been set\n' +
        '    at needs (/Users/xxxxx/xxxx/node_modules/@aws-crypto/material-management/src/needs.ts:21:11)\n' +
        '    at NodeDecryptionMaterial.getUnencryptedDataKey (/Users/xxxx/xxxx/node_modules/@aws-crypto/material-management/src/cryptographic_material.ts:417:10)\n' +
        '    at NodeDefaultCryptographicMaterialsManager.decryptMaterials (/Users/xxxxxx/yyyyyy/node_modules/@aws-crypto/material-management-node/src/node_cryptographic_materials_manager.ts:109:20)\n' +
        '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)'
    ]
  }
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: Does using this ARN make any difference? `arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:658956600833:key/b3537ef1-d8dc-4780-9f5a-55776cbb2f7f`

Comment: Also, note that you are using the AWS Encryption SDK, which is different to talking directly to AWS KMS - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-kms/index.html for comparison.

Comment: using v3 works as expected, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MrsBookik can you share your way of solving it??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turns out I used the wrong values for `generatorKeyId` and `keyIds`, see below:

Wrong:

```
const generatorKeyId = 'alias/MyKms'
const keyIds = ['arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:************:alias/MyKms']

const keyring = new KmsKeyringNode({ generatorKeyId, keyIds })
```

Correct *(see [example from official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/js-examples.html))*:

```
const generatorKeyId = 'arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:************:alias/MyKms'
const keyIds = ['arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:************:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab']

const keyring = new KmsKeyringNode({ generatorKeyId, keyIds })
```